# gridGraphics::grid.echo error: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graphics, cowplot

I'm trying to use `gridGraphics::grid.echo` according [to this link](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/52) so I can combine a `Gviz` `plotTracks` plot with a `ggplot` using `cowplot`'s `plot_grid`.

Following `Gviz`'s [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Gviz/inst/doc/Gviz.pdf) and [this link](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/52), here's what I do:

```
require(Gviz)
data(geneModels)
gtrack <- GenomeAxisTrack()
itrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "hg19", chromosome = as.character(geneModels$chromosome[1]))
grtrack <- GeneRegionTrack(geneModels, genome = "hg19",chromosome = as.character(geneModels$chromosome[1]), name = "Gene Model")

require(gridGraphics)

gwrap_plot <- function(x) {
  tree <- grid::grid.grabExpr(gridGraphics::grid.echo(x))
  u <- grid::unit(1, 'null')
  gtable::gtable_col(NULL, list(tree), u, u)
}

graphics.off()
plotTracks(list(itrack, gtrack, grtrack))
track.plot <- recordPlot()
gwrap_plot(track.plot)
```

And I get this error:

```
 Error in switch(x[[2]][[1]]$name, C_abline = C_abline(x[[2]]), C_plot_new = C_plot_new(x[[2]]),  : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

Any idea what's the problem of `gridGraphics`'s `grid.echo` with `Gviz`'s `plotTracks` plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid.echo` is for base graphics, Gviz appears to use `grid` graphics,

```
p1 = grid::grid.grabExpr(plotTracks(list(itrack, gtrack, grtrack), add = TRUE))
p2 = ggplot2::qplot(1:10, 1:10)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]